# Python-OpenCV forcing VideoWriter to use libx264 instead of libcuda.so.1

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, video, ffmpeg

I am using OpenCV for some video processing and require the output file to be in H264 encoded in an MP4 container. This is running on Ubuntu 16.04 in a Docker container, but I have also tested in Debian 9 (Stretch) and found the same issue. When the video writer begins to write to file, the following error occurs:

```
[h264_nvenc @ 0x7fd3c0468b60] Cannot load libcuda.so.1
Could not open codec ‘h264_nvenc’: Unspecified error
```

This seems to imply that nVidia cuda and nvenc is being used to encode the output video. This requires nVidia drivers to be installed, which is not an option right now.

The VideoWriter is created like so:

```
self.out = cv2.VideoWriter("test.mp4", cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264'), 30, (1280, 720))
```

As I understand it, OpenCV uses FFmpeg for video reading and writing video. My FFmpeg install has libx264 enabled- is there a way to force OpenCV to use FFmpeg & libx264 for video writing *instead* of libcuda and nvenc?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you compile `cv`  with `ffmpeg`?

Comment: What is the output of `ffmpeg -codecs | grep -i h264` in terminal?